# How to iterate Lua table from end?

Tags: lua, iterator, reverse, lua-table

How do I iterate a simple Lua table, that is [a sequence](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.7), from end?

Example of wanted behavior:

```
local mytable = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
for i, value in reversedipairs(mytable) do
    print(i .. ": " .. value)
end
```

should output

```
3: c
2: b
1: a
```

How to implement here `reversedipairs`?

Comment: Your iteration is more general than that. Meaning, it could work on table without so many restrictions. It simply iterates in reverse over the ["sequence"](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.7) of a table. If a table doesn't have a sequence, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @TomBlodget Thanks, I edited the question. I knew there has to be an official name for it, but I haven't found it anywhere.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Thank you, @Piglet, for useful link.

```
local function reversedipairsiter(t, i)
    i = i - 1
    if i ~= 0 then
        return i, t[i]
    end
end
function reversedipairs(t)
    return reversedipairsiter, t, #t + 1
end
```

Actually, I figured out an easier way may be to

```
local mytable = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
for i = #mytable, 1, -1 do
    value = mytable[i]
    print(i .. ": " .. value)
end
```

Comment: Good job coding this yourself, Idk why soneone didn't write it up and explain it though. It was a pretty simple task. Make sure to mark this as correct when it allows you :)

Answer (score 10):

Also you can use standard **for** statement with reversed index:

```
for i=1, #mytable do
   print(mytable[#mytable + 1 - i])
end
```